# I have a 3d matrix in matlab and I need to extract each row to create new matricies

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d matrix in the following form,

```
AA = [1,1;2,2];
BB = [1,1;2,2];
CC = [1,1;2,2];
ZZ = cat(3,AA,BB,CC)

NEW_CODE = [1 1; 1 1; 1 1; 2 2; 2 2; 2 2;]
```

Basically the code that I have creates a matrix in the form NEW_CODE, I need to transfer this back to ZZ.

To be clear, from

```
NEW_CODE =

     1     1
     1     1
     1     1
     2     2
     2     2
     2     2
```

To,

```
ZZ(:,:,1) =

     1     1
     2     2


ZZ(:,:,2) =

     1     1
     2     2


ZZ(:,:,3) =

     1     1
     2     2
```

I have tried this with no success,

```
attempt=NEW_CODE(:,1:3+1:end);
```

Comment: `attempt=permute(reshape(NEW_CODE,3,2,[] ), [2,3,1 ])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reshape` to split the top and bottom "halves" of the `NEW_DATA` matrix, then `shiftdim` to rearrange the result as desired

```
ZZ2 = shiftdim( reshape( NEW_CODE, [], 2, 2 ), 1 );
```

You can check this is correct using `isequal(ZZ,ZZ2)`, which returns true.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have a copy of Matlab to play with right now, so you're going to need to double check this

```
permute( reshape( NEW_CODE' , 2 , 3 , 2 ) , [ 1 3 2 ] )
```

Comment: 1. This doesn't give the correct output. 2. Please always include an explanation of the code either as comments with the code or as  a separate paragraph.

Comment: Note that `'` will conjugate the array if it has complex values